# HBase Shell datatype conversion

Tags: hbase

I am using `HBase cdh3u2`. in hbase shell I typed

```
put 'mytable', '2342', 'cf:c1', '67' (67 with quotes)
and
put 'mytable', '2341', 'cf:c1', 23 (23 without quotes)
and
put 'mytable', '2340', 'cf:c1', Bytes.toBytes(10)
```

And Using Java API i have put some values into the same table,

```
put.add(columnFamily,coulumnName,Bytes.toBytes(123));
```

and I done scan in hbase shell.
Except first two, all are stores data in the different format. I couldn't able to guess which method they used for converting as bytes `(Byets.toBytes())`.

Simply asking, hbase shell uses which method of `Bytes.toByte()`

Answer (score 2):

Hbase shell puts the values as strings, the last two option (Bytes.toBytes() in the shell and java) put the long value into the column and not the string representation